# Restyle list row design with extra text?

Tags: java, android

How can I restyle the theme of the list design?

I use a theme `android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock"`, and would like to preserve/extend this style. Just want to add another text element.

As for restyling, I assume I have to extends ArrayAdapter. There inflate the row styling. This means I have to define a `R.layout.row_styling.xml` myself.
How can I keep the whole row styling that is present in a included theme, but add another element?